# Can't set breakpoint in the class of DomainService

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I can't set breakpoint in the class of DomainService while debugging silverlight OOB application.Sorry for the miss of image,i'm a new user.

Comment: Set Breakpoint In Your DomainService In Web Application , not Use F11 Trace From Silverlight Project , if not breakpoint worked , perhaps your domainservice funtion called in you code but not execute .   excuse me for my english

Comment: Thanks Masoomian,but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press F5, it should normally work. Several problems could be the reason:

- you have to start Visual Studio as administrator, because you attach to another process
- check wheter the tag <compilation debug="true" /> is set in web.config

You can also directly attach to the executing process. Depending on operating system it is normally w3p.exe.

Comment: Thanks slfan,the probloem is partically solved when I start a new instance of the WebApplication.But strangely it can be debugged a few days ago without srating a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the ASP.NET debugger is selected in the project settings?

[image: Select Debuggers]